# How can I get only date and time value from timestamp value in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a Flutter project and I want to get 'timestamp' data from firestore and display that value using 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' format. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore will give you back a `Timestamp` object as I think you've figured out. It has a method [`.toDate()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp/toDate.html) which will return a dart `DateTime` object.

Once you have the Date object, then you should use the [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class as someone so helpfully pointed out in a comment without even linking to the documentation.

That would look something like this:

```dart
DateTime date = timestamp.toDate();
DateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").format(date);
```

although I haven't tested out the format function and dartpad doesn't seem to support the intl package, so you may need to play around with the format codes a bit.